# FindBugs - Boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed

Tags: java, findbugs

Getting Boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed error in following code snippet.
Please help me understand where is the issue?

```
     public Integer convert(String str) {
        String result = Optional.ofNullable(str)
            .filter(sStr -> sStr.length() != 0)
            .map(sStr -> sStr.substring(0, sStr.length() - 1))
            .orElse(StringUtils.EMPTY);
        return result.isEmpty() ? 1 : Integer.valueOf(result);
     }
```

FindBugs and SpotBugs show the warning: *Boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed* ([BX_UNBOXING_IMMEDIATELY_REBOXED](http://Bx:%20Boxed%20value%20is%20unboxed%20and%20then%20immediately%20reboxed)) for  the last statement of the method when rules with rank >= 18 are enabled.(not enabled by default at least in SpotBugs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ternary operator (`?:`) is a bit tricky in combination with boxing/unboxing. If `str` is not empty, your last line of code will:

1. Call the method `Integer.valueOf(String)`
2. This method calls `Integer.valueOf(parseInt(s, 10));` that converts an `int` value to an `Integer` object (first boxing)
3. Since you use an `int` value in the first part of the ternary operator, the returned `Integer` object is converted to an `int` value (unboxing)
4. Finally the `int` value is converted to an `Integer` object before the return (second boxing)

**To sum it up**: Instead of one `Integer` object the code creates two `Integer` objects. This is not really a problem in most scenarios.  Therefore the corresponding FindBug rule has only a rank of 18 and is by default disabled. The unecessary creation of the object could get a problem when your code is executed frequently in a high load scenario where the creation of millions of short-lived objects within a short period of time has negative impact on the garbage collector.

You can avoid this warning by either replacing `1` with `(Integer)1` or `Integer.valueOf(1)`. Both will produce the same byte code and avoid the unecessary creation of the second `Integer` object.